# Transferring data between two forms?

Tags: vb.net, forms

Okay so I've been searching for a solution for a while but can't seem to find any answers tailored to what I need to do. Also this is my first post here so I'm sorry if I'm being to vague with what I need. Basically I'm creating a program that has a few text boxes on one form and I need to display the data in those text boxes into a list box on another form. There's a button at the bottom of the first form that allows me to switch to form 2 and also display the data in the list box. I can switch to form 2 but nothing shows up in the list box. I also have a few radio buttons and check boxes on form 1 that will affect which constant values will need to show up in form 2's list box as well. One other thing is that I can't just use a form load option for getting data in the list box, it has to happen with the button press because I will be switching between forms and from my understanding the form load option only works once when the form is loaded for the first time. Anyway here is part of my code for form 1 that shows the button click:

```
Dim strCustomer As String
Private Sub btnPlaceOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlaceOrder.Click
    strCustomer = txtCustomer.Text
    frmInvoice.ShowDialog()
    frmInvoice.lstCustomerOrder.Items.Add(Me.strCustomer)
End Sub
```

My first form is frmMain and my second form is frmInvoice. Can anyone please help me with what I need to do differently with this code and what exactly I need to have for my code for form 2 to make this work. Again I am somewhat new to this so I'm sorry if any of this seems vague or if I'm not quite posting this is the right way. Also I'm using VB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass data from one form to another using a class (VB.Net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032538/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-another-using-a-class-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided should work fine but you are modifying the ListBox **after** you show the invoice Form. Since you are using **showDialog()**, the code that follows this statement will only be executed once the dialog form is dealt with (for example if you close it). This means that if you click the button a 2nd time, the ListBox should contain one item. If you switch the two lines so it looks like this, it should do what you expect it to:

```
frmInvoice.lstCustomerOrder.Items.Add(Me.strCustomer)
frmInvoice.ShowDialog()
```